# register_post_type name character limit

Tags: custom-post-types, limit, characters

I need to create a new custom post type, but the issue i am having is that the name i want to give is longer than 20 characters.

Is it possible to override this with a hook or filter?

I tried to modify this file in wp-includes `post.php` on line `1237`(`strlen > 20`), but this removed the  publish button and replace it with Submit for review.

Any idea how i fix this matter.

tanks.

Comment: Do you absolutely have to use a custom post type name of more than 20 characters? What is your aim?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change that value. The database schema is limited to 20 Bytes. See `wp-admin/includes/schema.php`:

```
TABLE $wpdb->posts (
  ID bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  post_author bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  post_date datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  post_date_gmt datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  post_content longtext NOT NULL,
  post_title text NOT NULL,
  post_excerpt text NOT NULL,
  post_status varchar(20) NOT NULL default 'publish',
  comment_status varchar(20) NOT NULL default 'open',
  ping_status varchar(20) NOT NULL default 'open',
  post_password varchar(20) NOT NULL default '',
  post_name varchar(200) NOT NULL default '',
  to_ping text NOT NULL,
  pinged text NOT NULL,
  post_modified datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  post_modified_gmt datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  post_content_filtered longtext NOT NULL,
  post_parent bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  guid varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  menu_order int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  post_type varchar(20) NOT NULL default 'post',
  post_mime_type varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  comment_count bigint(20) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (ID),
  KEY post_name (post_name),
  KEY type_status_date (post_type,post_status,post_date,ID),
  KEY post_parent (post_parent),
  KEY post_author (post_author)
)
```

If you need just longer **slugs in your URLs** you can do that in the argument `rewrite`:

```
register_post_type( 
    'yxz123', 
    array (
        'rewrite' => array (
            'slug'       => _x( 'really-long-slug', 'slug', 'custom_plugin_textdomain' ),
            'with_front' => FALSE
        ),
    ) 
);
```

Comment: thanks, i know it is not ideal, but i modified the table schema. Now everything seem to work fine. Do you think this will effect Wordpress anyway?

Comment: I don’t know if that will have side effects. But be aware some updates might change the schema back. I will add an alternative to my answer.